# Как реализовать такой же метод?

Tags: javascript

В общем, имеется у меня на сайте форма с классом `bot` и вот я хочу создать метод `on` как у телеграмм библиотеки, которая отслеживает, написал ли пользователь сообщение в чат и если написал, то выполнять какое-то действие, тоже как и в телеграмм библиотеки `sendMessage`
Просто пишу своего бота для сайта, вот хочу реализовать как у телеграмма

Код телеграмм библиотеки:

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Привет, Друг!');
});
```

На данный момент, у меня имеется класс JavaScript с названием Bot и в нем имеется метод on, который принимает параметр type, внутри данного метода у проверяется, нажал ли пользователь кнопку и если нажал, то я проверяю поле, пусто ли оно.
Мой код:

```
class Bot {

   on (type) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        if (msg.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')) {
         //
       }
   });
  }
```

Comment: Вы вообще не туда пошли. Библиотеке должно быть "до лампочки" на формочки, кнопочки, и т.д.. [Создаёте своё событие](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) `message` и используете его.

Comment: _метод on, который принимает параметр type, внутри данного метода у проверяется, нажал ли пользователь кнопку и если нажал, то я проверяю поле, пусто ли оно._ - нет, в этом методе происходит совсем не это.